# For which $z \in \mathbb C$ is $\left|\frac{z + i}{z - i}\right|\le 1 $?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

For which $z \in \mathbb C$ is $\left|\frac{z + i}{z - i}\right| \le 1$ ?

$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{z + i}{z - i}\right| = \left|\frac{a +bi + i}{a +bi - i}\right| =
\left|\frac{a + (1 + b)i }{a + (-1 + b)i}\right| &= 
\left|\frac{[a+(1+b)i][a-(-1+b)i]}{[a+(-1+b)i][a-(-1+b)i]}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{a^2-a(-1+b)i + a(1+b)i - (1+b)(-1+b)i^2}{a^2 - a (-1 + b)i + a(-1 + b) i - (-1+b)^2i^2}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{a^2 - a(-1+b)i + a(1+b)i + (1+b)(-1+b)}{a^2+ (-1 + b)^2}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{a^2+ai-abi+ai+bi+(-1+b-b+b^2)}{a^2+1+2b+b^2}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{a^2 + 2ai -abi + bi -1 + b^2}{a^2+1+2b+b^2}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{a^2+b^2-1+(2a-ab+b)i}{a^2+1+2b+b^2}\right| \\ 
&= \left|\frac{a^2+b^2-1}{a^2+2b+b^2+1} + \frac{(2a-ab+b)i}{a^2+1+2b+b^2}\right|| \\
&= \sqrt{\left( \frac{a^2+b^2-1}{a^2+2b+b^2+1} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{2a-ab+b}{a^2+2b+b^2+1} \right)^2}
\end{align}$

I am stuck in that step and do not know how to go on.

**Question**: Is there any technique to go on or do I have a mistake until now?

I think it might help if there is a way to simplify the equation so there will be no fraction any more and I can use the polynomial to determine when it is $\le 1$. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: What is the question exactly? For which $\left|\frac{z + i}{z - i}\right|$ and then what...?

Comment: sorry.. corrected that @StackTD

Comment: $a(1+b)i=ai+abi$, not $ai+bi$. Also, $a^2+(-1+b)^2=a^2+1-2b+b^2$, not $a^2+1+2b+b^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't want to carry out so many calculations.

***1 way of approaching this :***

$$\left|\frac{z + i}{z - i}\right| \le 1 \Rightarrow |z+i| \leq |z-i| 
  \quad\mathrm{since}  \quad |z-i| >0$$

Substituting $z=x+iy :$

$$|(x+iy)+i| \leq |(x+iy)-i| \Leftrightarrow |x+(y+1)i|-|x+(y-1)i|$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\sqrt{x^2 + (y+1)^2} - \sqrt{x^2 + (y-1)^2} \leq 0$$

***another one :***

$$\left|\frac{z + i}{z - i}\right| \le 1 \Rightarrow |z+i| \leq |z-i| 
  \quad\mathrm{since}  \quad |z-i| >0$$

So :

$$|z+i|^2 \leq |z-i|^2 \Leftrightarrow (z+i)(\overline{z+i}) \leq (z-i)(\overline{z-i})$$

Which should lead you to $\Im\{z\} \leq 0$.

Answer (score 6):

No wonder you're stuck. I wouldn't want to solve that square root either.

Rather, I would take the original inequality, and multiply on both sides by $|z-i|$ (assuming $z\neq i$) to get
$$
|z+i|\leq |z-i|
$$
which geometrically means that $z$ is closer to $-i$ than to $i$. In other words, these are the $z = a + bi$ for which $b\leq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\frac{z + i}{z - i}\right| \le 1 \\ \implies \left|z+i \right|\le \left| z- i \right| \\ \implies a^2+(b+1)^2 \le a^2+(b-1)^2 \\ \implies 4b \le 0$$

So this will hold $\forall z$ such that $Im(z)<0$

Answer (score 0):

For $z \ne i$ we have $\left|\frac{z + i}{z - i}\right|\le 1 \iff (*)  \quad |z+i|^2 \le |z-i|^2$

Now use $w \overline{w}=|w|^2$ and you should get $Im (z)\le 0$

Comment: Don't you mean Im(z)?

Comment: Ooops, you are right !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed by setting $z=a+bi$:

> $$\begin{align}
> \left|\frac{z + i}{z - i}\right| = \left|\frac{a +bi + i}{a +bi - i}\right| =
> \left|\frac{a + (1 + b)i }{a + (-1 + b)i}\right|\end{align}$$

Now:

$$\left|\frac{a + (1 + b)i }{a + (-1 + b)i}\right| = \ldots = \sqrt{\frac{a^2+(b+1)^2}{a^2+(b-1)^2}}$$

Which means you want:

$$\frac{a^2+(b+1)^2}{a^2+(b-1)^2} \le 1 \iff \frac{(b+1)^2-(b-1)^2}{a^2+(b-1)^2} \le 0 \iff \frac{4b}{a^2+(b-1)^2} \le 0$$

So you find $b = \mbox{Im}(z) \le 0$.